# Printing the bottom half of a diamond whose size is defined by user

Tags: java

I am trying to get my program to print a diamond shape with a size defined by the user, but the bottom half is messed up and I'm not sure why. The \'s and /'s must be going down diagonally, with a V at the bottom, making a diamond shape. Can anyone explain what's causing it to mess up?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Boolean f = true;
    while (f) {
        System.out.print("Choose a diamond size: ");
        try {
            int diamondSize = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
                int g = 0;
                while (g < diamondSize +1) {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                    g++;
                }
                System.out.println("^");
                for (int i = 1; i <= diamondSize; i++)  {
                    for (int a = 0; a <= diamondSize - i; a++) {
                        System.out.print(" ");
                    }
                    for (int a = 1; a <= 2 * diamondSize - 1; a++) {
                        if (a == i || a == 0) {
                            System.out.print("/");
                            for (int n = 1; n < a * 2; n++) {
                                System.out.print(" ");
                            }
                            System.out.print("\\");
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }
                System.out.print("<");
                int e = 0;
                while (e <= diamondSize * 2) {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                    e++;
                }
                System.out.println(">");
                for (int i = diamondSize * 2; i >= diamondSize; i--)  {
                    for (int a = 1; a >= diamondSize; a--) {
                        System.out.print(" ");
                    }
                    for (int a = 1; a <= 2 * diamondSize - 1; a++) {
                        if (a == i || a == 0) {
                            System.out.print("\\");
                            for (int n = 1; n < a * 2; n++) {
                                System.out.print(" ");
                            }
                            System.out.print("/");
                            System.out.println();
                        }
                    }
                }
                int m = 0;
                while (m < diamondSize + 1) {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                    m++;
                }
                System.out.println("V");
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("RESETTING. Please type an integer this time.");
            }
                System.out.println("Make another diamond? Type yes or no: ");
                if (input.nextLine().equals("no")) {
                    System.out.print("Thanks for playing!");
                    System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This question is pretty well asked for a new user...

Comment: Could you give some example inputs and outputs? Also, catching Exception is considered poor style. You may want to consider NumberFormatException to be more precise. For example, your code might end up in that catch block from some other exception, but since you're really expecting a NumberFormatException, your code's behavior will be unpredictable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two main bugs in your code.  The first is that your second outer loop is counting on the wrong index.

When you print the top of the diamond, your outer loop is correct:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= diamondSize; i++) {
```

But when you print the bottom half, you are trying to loop over twice the size down to the size for some reason:

```
for (int i = diamondSize * 2; i >= diamondSize; i--) {
```

This should be:

```
for (int i = diamondSize; i >= 1; i--) {
```

The problem that this causes you is that when you aren't looping over the correct index values, you can't use that loop index in any of your later loops.

---

Your second error is that your first spaces print loop in the bottom half is trying to count down, but you have the starting value and condition reversed, and you're counting against a hardcoded `1` instead of the outer loop index of `i`.

This:

```
for (int a = 1; a >= diamondSize; a--) {
```

Should be this:

```
for (int a = diamondSize; a >= i; a--) {
```

### To Sum Up

Replace these two lines of your code:

```
            for (int i = diamondSize * 2; i >= diamondSize; i--)  {
                for (int a = 1; a >= diamondSize; a--) {
```

With this:

```
            for (int i = diamondSize; i >= 1; i--) {
                for (int a = diamondSize; a >= i; a--) {
```

### P.S.

As a stylistic issue, your code is extremely hard to read and debug because of unnecessary
complexity.  You should really consider refactoring some of the common work (such as printing spaces) out into their own methods.  I was unable to debug your code until I had substantially re-written it.

For instance, you can refactor out all the space-prints loops by writing a method like this:

```
private static void printSpaces(int spaces) {
    for (int i = 0; i < spaces; i++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
}
```

That would let you replace code like this:

```
            int g = 0;
            while (g < diamondSize +1) {
                System.out.print(" ");
                g++;
            }
```

with a call to that method like this:

```
            printSpaces(diamondSize + 1);
```

This doesn't change the behavior of your program, but it makes it easier for yourself and others to read it, and see what it's doing.

Comment: Wow. This is an impressive answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
for (int a = 1; a <= 2 * diamondSize - 1; a++) {
    if (a == i || a == 0) {
        System.out.print("\\");
        for (int n = 1; n < a * 2; n++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.print("/");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

You are adding spaces after the "\" and before the "/". However, you need to place hald the spaces before the "\" and half after.

I've tried to bugfix it but I can't really make head or tail out of your many nested blocks and stuff, but I'm sure you can figure this one out. Sorry about that.

Comment: He tries to add spaces before in the first nested for-loop (`for (int a=1; a>=diamondSize; a==)`) but that loop never executes since he always starts a at 1.

Comment: Too much nesting, I also tried to step through it and just got lost. The second outer for-loop loops and extra time and doesn't print due to later checks, etc...

Comment: Got it, after much refactoring